# How to find instantiation of a class in C++ source code?

Tags: c++

When browsing unknown code, it is often helpful to see where a certain class is instantiated.

Given a class `MyClass`, how do I search the code to find the locations where `MyClass` is instantiated?
Just searching the name of the class will usually yield far too many occurrences of where the class is used in function or member declarations. So it isn't useful.
How to limit these and only show up the instantiations?
Is there a Regex for this?
It should at least handle cases like:

```
MyClass a;
DerivedClass b = MyClass(xyz);
AddItem(new MyClass(xyz));
```

Of course it is possible that the class will not be instantiated directly anywhere, but serve as a base class. I'm not considering these cases, as it would make things too difficult I guess.

Comment: You rightclick on `MyClass` and select "Show Usages" or something similar. You can also write a clang tool that prints all instantiations of a given class in case you want to reimplement what IDEs already do.

Comment: Look into the `clang-query` tool.

Comment: @nwp: no such function in MS Visual Studio 2013 Pro unfortunately. Nor in Visual Assist.

Comment: @Scrontch I'm guessing nwp meant "Find all References", and you can use it on a constructor. However I'm not sure whether it will catch usages as in the first line of your example.

Answer (score 8):

1) Make `MyClass`'s constructors private

2) Compile

3) Read the error messages

4) Revert

Comment: Nice one. Although a bit tedious when the project takes 15+ mins to build.